# Plotting mean and SE with facet wrap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a dataset (b.data) containing information on marine species recorded in a survey. Each row relates to an individual animal with the column headings below:

"Area" "Year" "Cruise" "Vessel" "Haul" "Haul_ID" "Common_name" "Scientific_Name" "Length_mm" "Sex" 
"Width"

I want to plot a graph showing the mean number of each species (with SE) for each area (3 survey areas). I have written the code below which gives me the graph I want but using raw data rather than the mean and SE.

```
species.area <- qplot(Common_name, data = b.data., geom = "bar") + facet_wrap(~ Area)

species.area + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You would make ik a lot easier for others to help you, if you provide a [reproducable example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258460/standard-error-bars-using-stat-summary), it uses [stat_summary](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_summary.html) from ggplot2.