# ggplot errorbar position multi-factor problems

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, errorbar

I've been trying to plot standard error bars over a multilevel histogram of data that is very similar to the following:

```
mth<-rep(c("June","July","August"),length.out=15)
yr<-rep(c("1999","2000","2005","2009","2010"),each=3)
X<-rnorm(15,mean=200,sd=100)
lng<-rep(c(30,31,31),length.out=15)
vrnc<-rnorm(15,mean=740,sd=300)
df<-data.frame(mth,yr,vrnc,lng,X)
dfi<-dim(df)[1]
for(i in 1:dfi){
df$X.se[i]<-sqrt(df$vrnc[i]/df$lng[i])
}
```

I've tried placing error bars using the stat_summary method described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258460/standard-error-bars-using-stat-summary). My code with stat_summary looks like this:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=yr,y=X,fill=mth))+
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar",position=position_dodge(1)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.ymin=min,fun.ymax=max,geom="errorbar",
        color="grey40",position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) +
    geom_errorbar(data=df,aes(ymin=X-X.se,ymax=X+X.se,position="dodge",width=.2))+
    scale_fill_discrete("mth")
```

I've also tried using this code:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=yr,y=X,fill=mth))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
    geom_errorbar(data=df,aes(ymin=X-X.se,ymax=X+X.se,position="dodge",width=.2))
```

but the result always comes out with the error bars all in the middle of each year.

[image]

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong. each error bar should be on top of the month/year referenced in the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

had to do this recently.  something like:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=yr,y=X,fill=mth))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=X-X.se, ymax=X+X.se), position = position_dodge(.9), width=.2)
```

Comment: Just a bit of further explanation: the main reason the errorbars weren't dodging is that `position` needs to be specified *outside* of the `aes()` mapping.

Comment: @RichAtMango: Bingo! Thank you so much.