# How to produce barchart with error bar using ggplot for two categorical variables in R?

Tags: r

I want to plot a bar chart for two categorical variables displaying CI for the proportion using ggplot.

This is something I've tried. The cut and clarity variables of the diamond dataset have more categories than my data but it doesn't matter. The graph produce from below code is pretty close to what I want as a final graph, I just want to add 95% CI of the proportion and error bar to the graph.

```
N <- diamonds %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, group = clarity)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = clarity), stat = "count") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales:: percent(..prop..), 
                y = ..prop..), stat = "count", vjust = -.5) + 
  labs(y = "Percent", title = "Distribution of diamond clarity by cut",fill = "Clarity") + 
  facet_grid(~clarity) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

N

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out these examples?: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258460/standard-error-bars-using-stat-summary

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already checked the website you provided. The examples they used is numeric variable. Mine are two categorical variables. Basically, I want to do two sample z test for proportion to include CI in the final graph.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258460/standard-error-bars-using-stat-summary this solution works for a numeric variable, while in my case, both variables that I want to plot in the graph are categorical variables.