# How to calculate standard error instead of standard deviation in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I need some help to figure out to estimate the standard error using the following R script:

```
 library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(Hmisc)

data("ToothGrowth")
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
head(ToothGrowth, 4)

theme_set(
  theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position = "top")
)

# Initiate a ggplot
e <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len))

# Add mean points +/- SD
# Use geom = "pointrange" or geom = "crossbar"
e + geom_violin(trim = FALSE) + 
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_sdl",  fun.args = list(mult = 1), 
    geom = "pointrange", color = "black"
  )

# Combine with box plot to add median and quartiles
# Change fill color by groups, remove legend
e + geom_violin(aes(fill = dose), trim = FALSE) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Many thanks for the help
Kind regards

Comment: You can use `fun.data = "mean_se"` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard error bars using stat\_summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258460/standard-error-bars-using-stat-summary)

Comment: @teunbrand I used mean_se for standard error and also tried mean_cl_normal for 95%CI along with standard deviation; but I couldn't see any changes between them. Could you please check the edited version of my original question that has now a screenshot too. Thanks for the comments

Comment: It is for the `stat_summary()` version of the plot, I wouldn't know how to do it with the boxplot. Notice that when you use the `stat_summary()`, you don't save the object. Hence, when you make the boxplot, it doesn't have the `stat_summary()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things. First, you need to reassign `e` when you add `geom_violin` and `stat_summary`. Otherwise, it isn't carrying those changes forward when you add the boxplot in the next step. Second, when you add the boxplot last, it is mapping over the points and error bars from `stat_summary` so it looks like they're disappearing. If you add the boxplot first and then `stat_summary` the points and error bars will be placed on top of the boxplot. Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(Hmisc)

data("ToothGrowth")
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

theme_set(
  theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position = "top")
)

# Initiate a ggplot
e <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len))

# Add violin plot
e <- e + geom_violin(trim = FALSE) 

# Combine with box plot to add median and quartiles
# Change fill color by groups, remove legend
e <- e + geom_violin(aes(fill = dose), trim = FALSE) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")

# Add mean points +/- SE
# Use geom = "pointrange" or geom = "crossbar"
e + 
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_se",  fun.args = list(mult = 1), 
    geom = "pointrange", color = "black"
  )
```

You said in a comment that you couldn't see any changes when you tried `mean_se` and `mean_cl_normal`. Perhaps the above solution will have solved the problem, but you should see a difference. Here is an example just comparing `mean_se` and `mean_sdl`. You should notice the error bars are smaller with `mean_se`.

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len)) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_sdl",  fun.args = list(mult = 1), 
    geom = "pointrange", color = "black"
  )
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len)) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_se",  fun.args = list(mult = 1), 
    geom = "pointrange", color = "black"
  )
```

Here is a simplified solution if you don't want to reassign at each step:

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len)) + 
  geom_violin(aes(fill = dose), trim = FALSE) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se",  fun.args = list(mult = 1), 
               geom = "pointrange", color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: thank you so much for the hints; it works fine :-) kind of you