# R: Show % differences between values: how to calculate error bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to show percentual change between groups. As a base approach, I wanted to compare the all groups' means to a defaut value, and just show those differences in [%]. I wish however to somehow represent the variability within the means, let's say in terms of standard deviations. But, I am not sure how to show this and actually if it does make sense?

Here is my example of simple bar plotting of the means and error bars, calculated as `mean` and `sd`:

```
dd <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2,3), 2),
                 vol = c(10,5,8,11,10,9),
                 reg = rep(c('control', 'new'), each = 3))


# calculate mean and sd
sum_dd <- dd %>% 
  group_by(reg) %>% 
  summarize(V_mean = mean(vol, na.rm = T),
            V_sd = sd(vol, na.rm = T)) #

# Plot bar plot and error bars
sum_dd %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reg,
             y = V_mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=reg,
                    min=V_mean-V_sd, 
                    ymax=V_mean+V_sd)) #
```

This plotting generates nice bar plot with error bars, wherw it is obvious what are my `means` and `sd` for each group:

[image]

But, how to express that the group `new` is a % change from `control`?

Here, I need to first calcualte the % change from `control` to `new`. Then I can plot the bar of the percentual change. But from which values I can calculate something like standard deviations to plot and show the variability (using e.g., error bar) in my results ?

```
sum_dd %>% 
  group_by(reg) %>% 
  # Calculate % change from a to b value
  mutate(control_mean   = 7.67,
         perc_change = (10-7.67)/7.67 * 100) %>%
  filter(reg !='control') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reg,
             y = perc_change)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') #+
# from which values calculate the error bar??
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=reg,
                    min=V_mean-V_sd, 
                    ymax=V_mean+V_sd)) # +
```

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can get your original plot using `stat_summary()` more easily because it will calculate the `mean` and `SD` for you directly inside the `ggplot()` call.

But to your question, you easily calculate the fold change prior to passing to `ggplot()` by doing a `mutate()` where you set `vol[reg == "control"]` as the denominator. Then you can format the `y` axis using {scales}.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

dd <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2,3), 2),
                 vol = c(10,5,8,11,10,9),
                 reg = rep(c('control', 'new'), each = 3))


# original plot using stat_summary to avoid transforming data
dd %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reg, vol)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_cl_normal, fun.args = list(mult = 1))
```

[image]

```r
# calculate % of control
dd %>% 
  mutate(norm_vol = vol/mean(vol[reg == "control"])) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reg, norm_vol)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_cl_normal, fun.args = list(mult = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: By the way for more details on how to calculate different summary statistics in the error bars see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258460/standard-error-bars-using-stat-summary) question.